# How to remove an item from a list of Path?

Tags: python, python-3.x, path

I have a `list of lists`, where I do have the path of all my training images, like the below one.

```
from pathlib import Path
image_list = [[Path('/home/0_knowle/Desktop/project/data/train/Image/Folder_1/Image_033_S_0724_Img_Na__Ma_F_.png'),
  Path('/home/0_knowle/Desktop/project/data/train/Image/Folder_2/Image_033_S_0724_Img_Na__Ma_F_.png')],

 [Path('/home/0_knowle/Desktop/project/data/train/Image/Folder_1/Image_033_S_0733_Img_Na__Ma_F_.png'),
  Path('/home/0_knowle/Desktop/project/data/train/Image/Folder_2/Image_033_S_0733_Img_Na__Ma_F_.png')],

  [Path('/home/0_knowle/Desktop/project/data/train/Image/Folder_1/Image_034_S_0733_Img_Na__Ma_F_.png'),
  Path('/home/0_knowle/Desktop/project/data/train/Image/Folder_2/Image_034_S_0733_Img_Na__Ma_F_.png')]
  ]
```

Now, I want to remove one item from the list based on a portion of the path (specifically, based on the last part of the path). Say, I want to remove one element from the list whose name starts with `Image_033_S_0733...`.

I was trying to

```
final_list = []
for sub_list in listA:
   for sub_sub_list in sub_list:
       if "Image_033_S_0733" not in sub_sub_list.name:
           final_list.append(sub_sub_list)
```

I am getting a flat list instead of a list of lists. The shape of the `image_list` is `(77, 2)`. The expected output is (after removing the item from the list of lists) `(76, 2)` but I am getting `(228, )`.

Is it possible to remove an item from a list of PosixPath?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `.name` attribute to get the filename from a `Path` object.

So replace the condition in your loop or list comprehension with:

```
'Image_044_S' not in item.name
```

To get a nested loop over results, use nested list comprehensions.

```
final_list = [
    [item for item in sub_list if "Image_033_S_0733" not in item.name]
    for sub_list in image_list]
```

Comment: Will it solve the problem tho? The problem is that `image_list` is somewhere above in his code defined as `PosixPath` and when he tries to iterate over image_list with `for item in image_list` he gets `TypeError`

Comment: @sudden_appearance I believe that error is coming from `'Image_044_S' not in item`, since `item` is a `PosixPath`.

Comment: I am getting `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'name'`

Comment: Is `image_list` the first list or the second one?

Comment: `image_list` is the first one (training images; list of list)

Comment: `.name` works for the second one (list)! Not for the second one.

Comment: You can't use the same loop for both. The first one needs nested loops.

Comment: The error you got in the question looks like it was the second list.

Comment: Thanks for the update. But, my actual list shape is `(77, 3)`, so, if I remove one, then I should get `(76, 3)`. But, I am getting `(228,)` after using the nested loop suggested in the answer. That's means, the list structure has been changed.

Comment: I thought you wanted a flat list like you showed. I'm having to make lots of assumptions because the question isn't very clear.

Comment: This question isn't really about the iteration, it's just about how to check if the filename is in a Path object.

Comment: I am extremely sorry that the question seems ambiguous. Yes, you are right. I wanted to check the filename and then later wanted to remove it from the list. I am editing the question to make it more clear.

Comment: I've removed the looping from my answer. I assume you know how to loop over your data to get the result you want, and I just show how to do the correct test.

Comment: Do you mean `[item for item in image_list if 'Image_044_S' not in item.name]` I am getting the same error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'name'`

Comment: If you have nested lists you need nested list comprehensions.

Comment: @Barmar when I am using nested loop and appending based on the condition `final_list = []
for sub_list in image_list:
    for sub_sub_list in sub_list:
        if "Image_033_S_0733" not in sub_sub_list.name:
            final_list.append(sub_sub_list)`. But, the shape of the `final_list` is getting changing to (228, )

Comment: That's the same as the list comprehension I wrote earlier. I've updated the answer to show how to do NESTED list comprehensions.

Comment: Thank you, I tried the same approach (using a loop), but the problem was I was getting an empty `list` inside the resulted `list`. Say for the given example in the question, I am getting `(3, )` but it should be `(2, 2)`. Same thing is happening for your given code